# Smart client software factory view activation

Tags: .net, scsf

I'm using smart client software factory in our application

I created one workspace dynamically,based on that I can create n numbers of views.the view is modal dialog and I have used some window workspace.

But the problem is I have to implement save all functionalities in menu.

But I don't know which view is activated/focused.

How to get the focused screen,is their any event will fore if on focus change?

Answer (score 1):

May be this post will help you:
[How To: Get the active view across multiple workspaces in a SCSF application](http://blogs.southworks.net/mconverti/2008/08/04/how-to-get-the-active-view-across-multiple-workspaces-in-a-scsf-application/)